# How to solve PHP notice : Undefined offset: 0?

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I want to import data excel to table on my database and the code like this :

```
    foreach ($data as $value) {
    \Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert(
        Route::tableName(),
        [
            'route', 'point_1', 'point_2',,
        ],
        [
            [
                $value[0][1], $value[0]['2'], $value[0][3]
            ]
        ]
        )->execute();
}
```

unfotunatelly, i have error notice on the end of import progress `Undefined offset: 0`. could someone here to help me to solve this error notice ?
Thank you.

Comment: well, just print `$value` or `$data` using `var_dump($value);` and check if the index 0 exists

Comment: on which line does this error occur?

Comment: `$value` is not an array

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky why do you mean? `$data` could be a multidimensional array

Comment: @Adi remove the `[0]` by `$value`, and show us what you get now

Comment: @Lino i get `Undefined offset: 1`